# CSS animation doesn't work in Mozilla

Tags: css, firefox, animation, mozilla

Can anyone see what I do wrong? I'm trying to make my animation css work in Firefox but somehow, it still doesn't work.

```
                    .animatietekst {
                        -webkit-animation: scaling 1s 10 ease;
                        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
                        -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
                        -moz-animation: scaling 1s 10 ease;
                        -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
                        -moz-animation-direction: alternate;
                    }

                    @-webkit-keyframes scaling {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.96);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
}

                    @-moz-keyframes scaling {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.96);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Take off the prefixes?  Firefox has had unprefixed support since version 16: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Aren't you using wrong `webkit-` prefixes in your `@-moz-keyframes` code block?

Comment: i guess you should take a look at this `https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/animation/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox doesn't recognise `webkit` transforms

```
@-moz-keyframes scaling {
        from {
            -moz-transform: scale(0.96);
        }
        to {
            -moz-transform: scale(1);
        }
    }
```

In any case you don't need the `moz` prefix any more

```
@keyframes scaling {
        from {
            transform: scale(0.96);
        }
        to {
           transform: scale(1);
        }
    }
```

will work just fine with

```
   .animatietekst {
     -webkit-animation: scaling 1s 10 ease;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
     animation: scaling 1s 10 ease;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    }
```